# couchbase command while docker setup

Tags: docker, docker-compose, couchbase

I am running couchbase using docker[on windows]. When I start it ask for doing cluster setup.

I want to customize docker-compose file to do below setup

```
1. set a cluster name
2. set up a admin account
3. create a empty bucket.
```

My docker compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  couchbase:
    image: couchbase/server
    ports:
      - 11210:11210
      - "8091-8094:8091-8094" 
    volumes:
      - /opt/couchbase/data:/opt/couchbase/var
    env_file: .env
```

Answer (score 4):

You can read about a solution here [using Couchbase with Docker Compose](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-using-docker-compose/) - behind the scenes it uses REST API calls to initialize the database and create buckets.

His docker file includes a configuration script to this:

```
FROM couchbase/server:enterprise-4.5.0-DP1

COPY configure-node.sh /opt/couchbase

CMD ["/opt/couchbase/configure-node.sh"]
```

You can find contents of the script [here on Github](https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/tree/master/couchbase) as a good starting point.

Comment: The same could probably be done with just a volume mount and `command` in compose file